# syslog time is not matching cron string setup

Tags: cron, syslog

I am running many cronjobs in my server. When I was checking the syslog file to see the cron timing, it's completely not matching. Can someone help me to understand.

syslog

```
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20251]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live Country_fn)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20252]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live CityNames_Low_fn)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20253]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live bloggerContact)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20268]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live cronCountryNames_High_fn)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20271]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live googleplus_state_fn)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20272]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live facebook_state_fn)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20269]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live googleplus_country_fn)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20244]: (munin) CMD (if [ -x /usr/bin/munin-cron ]; then /usr/bin/munin-cron; fi)
May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20277]: (root) CMD (php index.php cron_live cronCityNames_High_fn)
```

I sets the `00 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23 * * *` cron string to **googleplus_country_fn** job. which means it should execute (`2am, 5am, 8am, 11am, 2pm, 5pm, 8pm, 11pm`) times only. but syslog show it ran on `May 23 00:00:01 xxxxxx CRON[20269]`.

What is that syslog time is that starting time or ending or running time. Can someone help me to understand.

Edit: - 
full cron setup

`00 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23 * * * php index.php cron_live googleplus_country_fn`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the relevant cron line. The entire line, exactly as it is in your crontab.

Comment: @terdon: I added the full cron setup.

Comment: Which file did you save your cron setup to?

Comment: normally I do by ``crontab -e``. location of the file is ``/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root``